# Node process suddenly hit 100% CPU in EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io, cpu

I am running Node application (Socket.io) in AWS EC2(2CPU-4gbRAM) with Loadbalancer and Autoscaling setup, I've set Systemd for the Node service and it runs fine for a day with only 1% CPU the next day it's not working.
When I check details with `TOP` Node CPU utilization is 100%, but it shows only 50% usage in AWS Monitor and it stands there.
[image]

[image]

From various references, I'm not able to find the area of high consumption, root cause.
Please help me to figure out why Node hit only one CPU and what's the cause of high consumption.

From `cat /proc/PID/status`

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea how anyone could help without seeing more diagnostics and without seeing relevant code.  It's seems you're likely in some loop consuming CPU or perhaps retrying something over and over.  You say you can find the "area of high consumption".  So, what is the area?  What is the code doing in that area?  Please show the code for that area.

Comment: It's not possible to say this without deeping really deep into your code. Clearly, there are plenty of node processes running on millions of servers on the internet right now that do not exhibit this behavior, so it has to be specific to your code (obviously). I would read up about node debugging, and add a lot of logging to the code to see what it is doing.\

Comment: Actually, the scenario is this same setup is running fine in stage setup for a long time without any change in source code or server configuration. 
It will be helpful if you let me know how to find describe the running node process
@jfriend00, I'm mentioning the area where I could find the exact cause of Node Process CPU consumption

Comment: Something is likely different in the two configurations and perhaps you're getting errors in the troubling configuration.  In cases like this, I first review the entire code and make sure that every single possible error anywhere in the code is getting logged and paid attention to.  Then, if that doesn't turn up any good info, I start inserting log statements all through the code and use like a binary search to keep add finer and finer grain log statements until I can pinpoint exactly which are of the code is causing the issue.  There is no magic tool that will tell you where the problem is.